# Finding a lagged cumulative total from a table containing both cumulative and delta entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL table with a schema where a value is either a cumulative value for a particular category, or a delta on top of the previous value. While I appreciate this is not a particularly great design, it comes from an external source and thus I can't change it in any way.

The table looks something like the following:

```
Date    Category        AmountSoldType     AmountSold
-----------------------------------------------------
Jan 1   Apples          Cumulative            100
Jan 1   Bananas         Cumulative             50
Jan 2   Apples          Delta                  20
Jan 2   Bananas         Delta                  10
Jan 3   Apples          Delta                  25
Jan 3   Bananas         Cumulative             75
```

For this example, I want to produce the total cumulative number of fruits sold by item at the beginning of each day:

```
Date    Category      AmountSold
--------------------------------
Jan 1   Apples            0
Jan 1   Bananas           0
Jan 2   Apples          100
Jan 2   Bananas          50
Jan 3   Apples          170
Jan 3   Bananas          60
Jan 4   Apples          195
Jan 4   Bananas          75
```

Intuitively, I want to take the most recent cumulative total, and add any deltas that have appeared since that entry.

I imagine something akin to

```
SELECT Date, Category
       LEAD((subquery??), 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Date) AS Amt
FROM Fruits
GROUP BY Date, Category
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

is what I want, but I'm having trouble putting the right subquery together. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to add the deltas to the most recent cumulative -- all before the current date.

If so, I think this logic does what you want:

```
select f.*,
       (max(case when date = date_cumulative then amountsold else 0 end) over (partition by category
           ) +
        sum(case when date > date_cumulative then amountsold else 0 end) over (partition by category order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
           )
       ) amt
from (select f.*,
             max(case when AmountSoldType = 'cumulative' then date else 0 end) over
                 (partition by category order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current_row
                 ) as date_cumulative
      from fruits f
     ) f
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by this data set (notwithstanding the mistake in adding up the apples). I assume the raw data states end-of-day figures, so for example 20 apples were sold on Jan 2 (because there is a delta of 20 reported for that day).

In your example results, it does not appear valid to say that zero apples were sold on Jan 1. It isn't actually possible to say how many were sold on that day, because it is not clear whether the 100 cumulative apples were accrued during Jan 1 (and thus should be excluded from the start-of-day figure you seek) or whether they were accrued on previous days (and should be included), or some mix of the two. That day's data should thus be null.

It is also not clear whether all data sets must begin with a cumulative, or whether data sets can begin with a delta (which might require working backwards from a subsequent cumulative), and whether you potentially have access to multiple data sets from your external source which form a continuous consistent sequence, or whether "cumulatives" relate purely to a single data set received. I'm going to assume at least that all data sets begin with a cumulative.

All that said, this problem is a simple case of firstly converting all rows into either all deltas, or all cumulatives. Assuming we go for all cumulatives, then recursing through each row in order, it is a case of either selecting the `AmountSold` as-is (if the row is a cumulative), or adding the AmountSold to the result of the previous step (if it is a delta).

Once pre-processed like this, then for a start-of-day cumulative, it is all just a question of looking at the previous day's cumulative (which was an end-of-day cumulative, if my initial assumption was correct that all raw data relates to end-of-day figures).

Using the LAG function in this final step to get the previous day's cumulative, will also neatly produce a null for the first row.